# CQ5, dynamically set 'defaultValue' in component's dialog using extjs?

Tags: extjs, dialog, content-management-system, components, aem

I have a selection box in my component's dialog, with four options:

- off
- default
- addon
- overwrite

In the dialog, I want dynamically set the `defaultValue` property to 'off' or 'default' based on whether the URL path contains a certain characters or not.  Is this possible?

Here is the dialog.xml snippet with my attempted listener to do this:

```
<extra_meta_description_tag_mode
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    defaultValue=""
    fieldLabel="SEO Description Usage"
    name="./extraMetaDescriptionTagMode"
    type="select"
    xtype="selection">    
        <listeners
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            defaultValue="function(url) {
                url.contain("en_gb/news") ? return "default" : return "off"; 
            }"/>
        <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <off
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                text="Off"
                value="off"/>
            <default
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                text="Append pre-set text"
                value="default"/>
            <addon
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                text="Append input text"
                value="addon"/>
            <over_write
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                text="Overwrite"
                value="overwrite"/>
        </options>
</extra_meta_description_tag_mode>
```

Comment: Does the URL path mean the path of the current page or is it something else?

Comment: ye, path of the current page, e.g  /content/sometestweb/en-gb/news/testnews.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The listener can only have values of events, defaultValue is not one. You can use the loadContent event,which is fired when the dialog loads. `CQ.WCM.getPagePath()` will give the current page path:

```
<listeners
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    loadcontent="function(selection,record,path) {
        var currentPath = CQ.WCM.getPagePath();
        if(currentPath.indexOf('en_gb/news')!=-1)
        {  
            selection.setValue('default');
        } else { 
            selection.setValue('off');
        }"/>
```

This will reset the value every time the dialog loads, so you will have add conditions to prevent it if the users have overridden the default value.

Answer (score 0):

You could also give your component a itemId property with the value: "extra_meta_description_tag_mode", then write an ExtJS plugin and register it for xtype: "selection" and in the init method of your plugin, set the defaultValue property depending on the current page path.